# How to prove for every positive integers $k$ if the degree set of vertices of a graph is $(1,1,2,2,3,3,...,k,k)$ , we can create a graph.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction

How to prove  for every positive integers $k$  if the degree set of vertices of graph is $( 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 ,3 , .... , k , k )$ , we can create a graph .

For example if  $k = 3$ we can have a graph that has $6$ vertices that $\text{deg}(v_1)$ and $\text{deg}(v2)$ is $1$ , $\text{deg}(v_3)$ and $\text{deg}(v_4)$ is 2 and $\text{deg}(v_5)$ and $\text{deg}(v_6)$ is 3.

***This is what I tried :***

I could understand that in every case we have $2k$ vertices. And I think it can be solved by induction. We know that $p(1)$ is true that means it is possible to create a graph with $2$ vertexes with degree of $1$ for each of them.
actually I do not know how to prove for $p(k+1)$ please help me solve this proof in this way or another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: graphs]

Worth a thousand words, they say.

Comment: Nice, and you don't really need induction to define these -- by numbering the columns in opposite orders and indexing $1$ to $k$, it seems to be $x_i$ connected to $y_j$ IFF $i+j > k$

Comment: It would be even easier to number the columns in _the same_ order and say that $x_i$ is connected to $y_j$ iff $i\geqslant j$.